# A more efficient code for multiple .click events?

Tags: jquery

Instead of doing

```
$("#IsOutdoors").click(function () {
    SendData();
});

$("#HasPatio").click(function () {
    SendData();
});
```

Is there a better way if I want to do multiple .click evnts?
Thanks!

Comment: Other than taking out jQuery, no, not really.

Comment: You mean `$('#foo, #bar').click(...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use all your selectors in one string, and separate them with a comma:

```
$("#IsOutdoors, #HasPatio").click(function () {
    SendData();
});
```

---

For a more succinct version, you can pass the `SendData` function itself to `click`:

```
$("#IsOutdoors, #HasPatio").click( SendData );
```

Bewarned though that this will change the `this` value within `SendData`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#IsOutdoors,#HasPatio").click(SendData);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways:

- **Combine the selectors**
  Just like you would do in CSS, use a comma to target multiple selectors:
  `$("#IsOutdoors, #HasPatio").click(SendData);`
- **Add to the jQuery collection**
  You can add extra elements to an existing jQuery collection using [`$.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/). Since the individual selections are internally shortcut using `getElementById()` instead of a full `querySelectorAll()` or Sizzle, this may be more efficient.
  `$("#IsOutdoors").add("#HasPatio").click(SendData);`
- **Add a common class to the elements**
  This is not really a scripting solution, but if the elements are logically similar, a class may be appropriate.
  `$(".someClass").click(SendData);`

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by better. Do you want less code but the same outcome? You can do something like

```
$("#IsOutdoors, #HasPatio").click(SendData);
```

If you're looking to reduce the number of click handlers, say if you have multiple DOM elements that all have the same click handler, you can instead put the event hander on a parent element. You can then either list all of the IDs of the elements that this event should be delegated to or give them all a common class like `clickable`. Let's say your HTML looks like the following:

```
<div id='someParent'>
  <div id='IsOutdoors' class='clickable'></div>
  <div id='HasPatio' class='clickable'></div>
</div>
```

You can simplify your click handler to

```
$("#someParent").on('click', '.clickable", SendData);
```

or if you don't want to add the class like I suggested

```
$("#someParent").on('click', '#IsOutdoors #HasPatio", SendData);
```